# In Android WebView the `window.localStorage` object is sporadically `null` when the execution of JavaScript starts

Tags: android, webview, local-storage

I have a web application, which runs in an Android WebView. As the web application initializes himself, he reads some data from the local storage.

The problem is, that sporadically on some devices the `window.localStorage` object is `null` as the web app tries to do the initialisation which does the local storage operation. So not the values in the local storage are `null` but the `localStorage` itself is `null`. As if in this case the web view would start the JavaScript execution before the local storage would be ready. I was never able to reproduce this on a device that is in my hand, I only see this in the logs. Also on a device, where the issue happened once, it does not deterministically happen again.

Did someone else also meet this issue?
Would waiting for the `window.localStorage` object help? I'm asking because I'm not sure, if in this case the WebView is generally broken and I'm afraid that the `window.localStorage` might never be defined in these cases.

Comment: Did you check [`setDomStorageEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setDomStorageEnabled(boolean)),  
[`getDomStorageEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#getDomStorageEnabled()) ?

Comment: Yes, `domStorageEnabled` is set to `true` right next to `javaScriptEnabled`. As the JavaScript is able to run I assume, that both  `javaScriptEnabled` and `domStorageEnabled`  are set correctly.